# asp.net one more updatepanel is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I added 3 updatepanel on a aspx page.Two updatepanel includes gridview.And i make gridview paging.two buttons fill this gridviews when clicked.I set both of them triggers and conditional state.Third updatepanel includes textbox.And i set updatemode conditional,triggers third button.

That my question,when i click firstly third button i select checked datafield from gridview,run succesfully.
But when i click after one clicked,third updatepanel and gridview paging is not working.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelWorkFLow" runat="server">
    <%--<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGenerate" />
    </Triggers>--%>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridWorkFlow" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridWorkFlow_PageIndexChanging">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true" HeaderText="Seç">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkWorkFlow" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="labelWorkFlowId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkFlowId")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WorkFlow Adi">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="labelWorkFlowName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Birincil Entity Adi">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="labelPrimaryEntity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PrimaryEntity") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText="Durum Açiklamasi">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="labelWorkFlowStaus" runat="server" Text='<%#  GetStatusCodeText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"StatusCode"))%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnWorkFLow" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

my gridview paging code

```
    WorkFlowDataBind();
    GridWorkFlow.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridWorkFlow.DataBind();
```

my third button code

```
    string userQueryId = GetUserQueryId();
    string userqueryName = GetUserQueryName();
    string workFlowId = GetWorkFlowId();
    string primaryEntityName = GetWorkFlowPrimaryEntity();
    GetWorkFlowName();
```

my one and second button when clicked load gridview

```
    Datatable dtUserQuery=GetDataTable();
    GridUserQuery.DataSource = dtUserQuery;
    GridUserQuery.DataBind()
```

How can i fix.

Comment: Adam i edit my post by my codes

Comment: can you paste the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

Logic is .. If you have one or more update panel in the same page then properties of all update panel should be same such as if update panel data are dependency on each other

```
Update Mode : Always
EnableViewState : true(if you are using it)
```

Or you can explicitly update the Update panel when mode is conditional

Let us say you have two update panel like up1 and up2. 
You have placed the label in the up1 and the other form or button placed in the up2. 
Now on the click event in the up2, label placed in the up1 should be updated without loading the full page. Set the following stuffs

1. Set EnableParitialRendering ='True'(Script Manager)
2. Set Update Mode :Conditional(up1)
3. Set Update Mode : Always (up2). All set up done here. On click of a button in the up2, do your work and call up1.Update(); That's all.